# Unable to open Gparted in Ubuntu 19.04 though GUI and through Terminal

Tags: partitioning, gparted, 19.04

Unable to open GParted through GUI and Terminal, in terminal i ran gparted and it display's below error.

```
asool@finding:~$ sudo gparted
Unit tmp.mount does not exist, proceeding anyway.
/usr/sbin/gpartedbin: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgiomm-2.4.so.1: undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib17SignalProxyNormal13connect_impl_EbON4sigc9slot_baseEb
```

Comment: That error *usually* indicates your gparted and your system's libraries don't match each other, how'd you install GParted?  Do you have any customized repositories in use?

Comment: Thanks for reply, no, i have installed by running command "sudo apt-get install gparted"

Comment: No, Ubuntu installed on Physical Laptop

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i did as you suggested, but it shows the same error.

"rasool@finding:~$ xhost +localhost
localhost being added to access control list
rasool@finding:~$ gparted
Unit tmp.mount does not exist, proceeding anyway.
/usr/sbin/gpartedbin: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgiomm-2.4.so.1: undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib17SignalProxyNormal13connect_impl_EbON4sigc9slot_baseEb
"

Comment: Please run `sudo ldconfig` to create links for shared libraries that might be missing. Please read here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/man8/ldconfig.8.html. then try running `gparted` again. I would suspect outdated librarries or gparted package, but since you are running 19.04, I ruled that out. Best of luck

Comment: Still the same issue :(